# Replace multiple value of DataFrame column using loop (Outlier treatment)

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, replace, outliers

I am trying to replace the outlier values of "LotFrontage" columns
of my DataFrame by 5th percentile if values are lesser than min value
and if greater than max then cap at 95th percentile. I want to do this
using for loop only. I tried to write this simple function but this is
not working. I have been struggling on this from couple of days, I
could solve this using numpy but want to do this using for loop only.
Any help is appreciated

```
def outlier(x):
    # taking 5,25,75 percentile of column
    q5= np.percentile(x,5)
    q25=np.percentile(x,25)
    q75=np.percentile(x,75)
    dt=np.percentile(x,95)
    #calculationg IQR range
    IQR=Q3-Q1
    #Calculating minimum threshold
    min=q25-(1.5*IQR)
    max=q75+(1.5*IQR)
    #Calculating maximum threshold
    for i in x:
        if x[i] > max:
            x[i].replace(x[i],dt)
        elif x[i] < min:
            x[i].replace(x[i],q5)
        else:
            x[i]
    print(q5,q25,q75,dt,min,max)

    return
```

Applying above function to a column of DataFrame

```
outlier(Sdata["LotFrontage"])
```

Please let me know if you need any other informaion

Data:
[image]
I get below error when i apply this function on my column:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Could you try adding to you example the test data and also show how exactly do you call the function `outlier`?

Comment: I call function outlier using Sdata["LotFrontage"].apply(outlier)  , Please let me know if it helps. Test data is available in questions. let me know if you still do not find.

Comment: Alright, so I'm assuming that `Sdata` is a dataframe and `outliner` takes `Series` as input parameter.
I think that in your example if you do `for i in x` where x is a `Series` your iterating over values not index. So `i` is taking values: 70, 70, 80, etc.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iteritems.html
If you provided full code it'd be easier to debug it and say something more.

Comment: @lolnoob you are right. That is the only code i have where i want to replace outlier values of a column using For loop in function. but you have understood it right and complete code is seen in my questions.Seems like my code is not iterating,

Answer (score 0):

Rather than numpy or `for` loop, you can do this substitution using a simple assignment with `pandas`. Being `x` your `pandas.Series` inside the `outlier` function, you can replace the whole final `for` loop with:

```
x[x < vmin] = q5
x[x > vmax] = dt
```

and you're done.
Notice that here I renamed your `min` as `vmin` and your `max` as `vmax`. `min` and `max` are built-in python functions, naming variable like built-in python function may cause confusion.

However, since you asked a `for` loop, if you really want to use a loop, it should look like this:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] > vmax:
        x[i] = dt
    elif x[i] < vmin:
        x[i] = q5
```

because `i` need to be an index.

Finally, remember to `return x`. Your call should look like:

```
Sdata["LotFrontage"] = outlier(Sdata["LotFrontage"])
```

Comment: @Valentio  I have used altered code still i get same error.  def outlier(x):
   
    q5= np.percentile(x,5)
    q25=np.percentile(x,25)
    q75=np.percentile(x,75)
    dt=np.percentile(x,95)
    #calculationg IQR range
    IQR=Q3-Q1
 
    vmin=q25-(1.5*IQR)
    vmax=q75+(1.5*IQR)
    #Calculating maximum threshold
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i] > vmax:
            x[i]=dt
        elif x[i] < vmin:
            x[i]=q5
        else:
            x[i]
    #print(q5,q25,q75,dt,min,max)

    return x

Sdata["LotFrontage"]=outlier(Sdata["LotFrontage"])

Comment: Did you run this function on the data i have applied? For me still it gives the same error.

Comment: I cannot grab data from an image, hence I didn't try it on your data. I tried it using some random numbers and it worked. Try to `print(x)` and be sure it's a `Series`. The error suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `Sdata["LotFrontage"].apply(outlier)` it will actually call the function with each of the values in the `pd.Series` Sdata["LotFrontage"]. You want to run `outlier(Sdata["LotFrontage"])`.

**EDIT:**
Also you need to replace `for i in x:` with `for i,value in enumerate(x):`.

**EDIT**: Here is a possible solution:

```
def outlier(x):
    # taking 5,25,75 percentile of column
    q5= np.percentile(x,5)
    q25=np.percentile(x,25)
    q75=np.percentile(x,75)
    dt=np.percentile(x,95)
    #calculationg IQR range
    IQR=q75-q25
    #Calculating minimum threshold
    lower_bound=q25-(1.5*IQR)
    upper_bound=q75+(1.5*IQR)
    #Calculating maximum threshold
    print(q5,q25,q75,dt,min,max)
    return x.apply(lambda y: dt if y > upper_bound else y).apply(lambda y: q5 if y < lower_bound else y)

outlier(Sdata["LotFrontage"])
```

Comment: Can you please give me a solution for this loop. also, i request you to apply that loop on the data i have given as loop solution is not working in  my case.